# Как правильно собирать static библиотеку с "device" функциями?

Tags: c++, cmake, cuda

В общем - есть исходные, где "device" функции предоставляются для использования.
Я собираю библиотеку через `cmake`:

```
cuda_add_library(${LIB_NAME} STATIC ${SOURCES})
```

В дальнейшем, когда пытаюсь данную библиотеку подключить к любому внешнему проекту и "линкую" её с помощью `cmake`:

```
target_link_library(${EXE} ${LIB_NAME})
```

получаю ошибки:

> undefined reference to

в попытке использовать функции из своей библиотеки.

Comment: Разные версии с++ генерируют разные имена. (в borland есть приставка extern "C" она влияет на генерируемое имя). Что бы сопоставить имена используют def-файл. При линковании необходимо так же указывать obj или lib файлы с необходимыми функциями.

Comment: @nick_n_a по идее это и делает cmake когда "линкует" библиотеку к ${EXE}

Comment: это хорошо когда make-скрипт написан до вас (утилита cmake берёт make-скрипт и делает то что написано в make файле), а если вы пишете проэкт с нуля, вы можете случайно не включить библиотеку на линковку - соответственно и получите *undefined reference*. Есть правда вариант, когда make-скрипт генерирует среда-с++, тогда нужно правильно настроить опции проэкта. Т.е. два варианта - 1)пишите свой make-скрипт 2) внимательно смотрите опции компилятора. Как называется среда вашего c++? или вы с консоли всё собираете?